# How can I know in which step (Pre-Processor,Compiling, Linking) my program failed to compile?

Tags: c, header, linker, c-preprocessor

How can I know in which step (Pre-Processor,Compiling,  Linking) my program got compilation failure?

For example, I wrote a program of 3 source files: `a.c ,b.c, c.c` and all three of them included the header file, `h.h`, which contains all the prototypes of all the source files, but I also implemented one function, in the header file. I know it's wrong to do, but I wonder on what stage did the program crash, Is it the linking or the compiling, I got an error message, Is this say that the problem is at the linking stage? (otherwise I'll just get a red underline on the mistake from the compiler?)

Where can I read about linking and what I shouldn't do regarding headers and source files and linking errors?

(I work in Linux, with Eclipse)

Comment: The program usually crashes at runtime. Do you ask about compilation fail instead of crash?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the location of the error by separating compiling and linking. An error due to the precompiler is unusual and also found during compiling. This is how compiling works on the command line:

Compile step:

```
gcc -c -o a.o -pedantic -Wall a.c 
gcc -c -o b.o -pedantic -Wall b.c 
gcc -c -o c.o -pedantic -Wall c.c
```

link step:

```
gcc a.o b.o c.o -o prog
```

Of course you need to specify whatever other flags that are necessary (e.g. -l for linking to a library etc.)

Then read the errors and warnings (!) carefully and you shall find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your program *crashes* only once you have pre-procesed, compiled and linked your program to generate an executable that you can run. A crash is a *run-time* error.

*Re preprocessor/compilation/linking*:

You didn't specify what platform/environment you are working in, but in a Linux/Unix environment it is easy to determine if you are getting problems with the linker as you usually get a message with `ld`.

Compilation errors usually syntax related and easy to identify that way (e.g., mismatched parens, missing semi-colons, etc) (Aside, as a general rule, I would recommend you *always* compile with the highest warning level, and then *consciously* determine which warning messages to ignore.)

I am not at a system were I can try it out, so I'm not sure of the pre-processor throws out specific easily identifiable error/warning messages, or if they just  get passed on to the compiler and get spit out at that stage.

None of these steps crash your program, that only happens (if it does) after all these steps have been completed successfully.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question. I meant compilation fail instead of crash.

Comment: @Numerator .. just noticed, hope my answer helps.

Comment: errors in the preprocessed part lead to other errors which can affect compiling and / or linking-

Comment: @steffen Yes, that is true (and to be expected) as the PP passes its output to the compiler, which in turns passes to the linker